# Twint to Kafka -> Dont receive any events in my topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-kafka-python, twint

i'm trying to load some tweets via TWINT into a kafka topic with the confluent-kafka[avro]
Producer. I don't get any errors but my topic wont receive any events from twint. I even get succes msg, when debugging(with try and except).

My Code:

```
import twint
import sys
import json
from time import sleep
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer

# Define Avro schema
value_schema_str = """
{
   "namespace": "my.test",
   "name": "value",
   "type": "record",
   "fields" : [
         { "name": "id",        "type": "long"   },
         { "name": "tweet",     "type": "string" },
         { "name": "datetime",  "type": "string" },
         { "name": "username",  "type": "string" },
         { "name": "user_id",   "type": "long"   },
         { "name": "name",      "type": "string" }

   ]
}
"""
key_schema_str = """
{
   "namespace": "my.test",
   "name": "key",
   "type": "record",
   "fields" : [
     {
       "name" : "name",
       "type" : "string"
     }
   ]
}
"""

kafka_broker = 'host.docker.internal:9092'
schema_registry = 'http://host.docker.internal:8081'

value_schema = avro.loads(value_schema_str)
key_schema = avro.loads(key_schema_str)

producer = AvroProducer({
    'bootstrap.servers': kafka_broker,
    'schema.registry.url': schema_registry
    }, default_key_schema=key_schema, default_value_schema=value_schema)


module = sys.modules["twint.storage.write"]
   

def Json(obj, config):
    
    tweet = obj.__dict__
    tweet_new = {}
    tweet_new['id'] = tweet['id']
    tweet_new['tweet'] = tweet['tweet']
    tweet_new['datetime'] = tweet['datetime']
    tweet_new['username'] = tweet['username']
    tweet_new['user_id'] = tweet['user_id']
    tweet_new['name'] = tweet['name']
    print(tweet_new)
    try:
        producer.produce(topic='tweets_test', key={"name": "Key"}, value=tweet_new)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception while producing record value - {tweet_new} to topic - tweets_test: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"Successfully producing record value - {tweet_new} to topic - tweets_test")
    try:
        producer.flush()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception while flush record value - {tweet_new} to topic - tweets_test: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"Successfully flushed record value - {tweet_new} to topic - tweets_test")


module.Json = Json

c2 = twint.Config()
c2.Search = "corona OR regen OR \"stark regen\" OR \"sturm\" OR überschwemmung OR landunter OR @hagel OR @regen OR @sturm OR flut"
c2.Store_json = True
c2.Custom["user"] = ["id", "tweet", "user_id", "username", "hashtags"]
c2.User_full = True
c2.Output = "tweets.json"
c2.Since = '2019-05-20'
c2.Hide_output = True
twint.run.Search(c2)
```

When i run it i get the following output:

```
    {'id': 1513818741057937408, 'tweet': 'RKI: Bundesweite Sieben-Tage-Inzidenz steigt leicht auf 1087 | #corona #rki #test ', 'datetime': '2022-04-12 09:58:07 UTC', 'username': 'flashupde', 'user_id': 1179376986516606978, 'name': 'FLASH UP'}
Successfully producing record value - {'id': 1513818741057937408, 'tweet': 'RKI: Bundesweite Sieben-Tage-Inzidenz steigt leicht auf 1087 | #corona #rki #test  ', 'datetime': '2022-04-12 09:58:07 UTC', 'username': 'flashupde', 'user_id': 1179376986516606978, 'name': 'FLASH UP'} to topic - tweets_test
Successfully flushed record value - {'id': 1513818741057937408, 'tweet': 'RKI: Bundesweite Sieben-Tage-Inzidenz steigt leicht auf 1087 | #corona #rki #test  ', 'datetime': '2022-04-12 09:58:07 UTC', 'username': 'flashupde', 'user_id': 1179376986516606978, 'name': 'FLASH UP'} to topic - tweets_test
```

Any help how i can debug it better or any advice would be awesome.

Comment: Okay, that's your producer code. What exactly is supposed to be consuming data?

Comment: @OneCricketer i'm using the  kafka-avro-console-consumer.. Kafka is creating the topic but no message arive.. i am following this tutorial: https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2019/05/29/loading-tweets-twint-kafka-neo4j/

Comment: Well, are you passing `--from-beginning`? Or starting the consumer before you run the producer? Also, there are other ways you can be checking if messages are in the topic or not, such as GetOffsetShell or actually checking topic data on disk

Comment: Its working now. I had the wrong kafka_broker in my code... *facepalm* Thanks @OneCricketeer for your help, at least i got to know GetOffsetShell.